# I am trying to read gmail inbox using imap function (php). but it showing error

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to read gmail inbox using php imap function

showing error as

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream     {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in C:\xampp\htdocs\mail.php on line 10
Cannot connect to Gmail: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)
Notice: Unknown: Invalid credentials i9mb61071274pbk (errflg=1) in Unknown     on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Invalid credentials i9mb61071274pbk (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Invalid credentials i9mb61071274pbk (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Looks like you use wrong login/pass. Credentials are case sensitive.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable IMAP access to your Gmail account?

> 1. Sign in to the Google Admin console.
> 2. From the dashboard, go to Apps > Google Apps > Gmail > Advanced settings.
> 3. In the Organizations section, select the organizational unit for which you want to configure settings.
> 4. Under POP and IMAP Access, select or clear the check box for Disable > POP and IMAP access for all users in the domain.
>
> If you select the check box, POP and IMAP are fully disabled for all users in your domain.
>
> 1. Users cannot access POP and IMAP settings in the Gmail interface.
> 2. Users cannot access their mail via POP or IMAP even if they originally
>    had it on.
> 3. Users cannot access or search mail via Google Desktop
>    (which uses POP).
>
> If you clear the check box, POP is enabled for your
> users, but IMAP remains disabled.
>
> 1. POP access is automatically turned on for your users.
> 2. Users need to enable IMAP in the Gmail settings under Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
>
> It may take 15-30 minutes for IMAP and POP changes to take effect. As
> long as the box is cleared, users can configure POP and IMAP access
> for a host of clients.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694?hl=en

Comment: thanks i got the solution :https://arjunphp.com/reading-emails-from-gmail-using-php-imap/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google is having issues with IMAP at the moment. I'm experiencing similar issues with my mail client right now.

The Google Apps Status Dashboard at http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=fr&v=status doesn't list any disruption, however multiple posts on Twitter are mentioning it, and http://downrightnow.com/gmail shows service disruption.